# Assumption in DBSCAN Clustering

Tags: clustering, multicollinearity, assumptions, dbscan

Does the non-multicollinearity assumption apply to DBSCAN?

I've read that this clustering method makes no assumptions about the density or variance in clusters that may exist in the data set. Can that be used as a reason that DBSCAN does not need assumptions?

Comment: Not quite, for ex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN disadvantages point 3 `DBSCAN cannot cluster data sets well with large differences in densities, since the minPts-ε combination cannot then be chosen appropriately for all clusters.`, so it does make some assumptions of similar epsilon across all clusters.

Comment: DBSCAN has no problems at all with multicollinearity, but as @user2974951 points out (do you want to turn your comment into an answer?), that does not mean that it has no assumptions at all.